# Thymeleaf form doesn't send the actual object id to the Java controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So I have the following written in Thymeleaf:

```
<form th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}" method="post" id="recipeDeleteForm">
                             </form>
```

And the following in Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recipes/{recipeId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteRecipe(@PathVariable Long recipeId, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        Recipe recipe = recipeService.findOne(recipeId);
        recipeService.delete(recipe);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

The problem is that when I press the delete button on the browser, the request will only send the number 1 to the controller, instead of sending the specific object id. So it will always delete the first element from the list, not the one that I chose.

EDIT: Actually, this is incremental. If I delete a random object from the list first time, it will delete the first item from the list, if I delete another random element from the list, it will delete the second one, and so on...

Something else to add would be that this doesn't happen if I try to go to a detail page, or I try to edit the object. It will send the correct id to the controller. This happens only for the delete request.

An important difference here would be that the edit and detail actions are links, and delete is a form action.

This is how the entire markup file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head th:replace="layout :: head"></head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="layout :: nav"></nav>

<div class="grid-container">

    <div th:replace="layout :: logo"></div>

    <div class="grid-100">

        <div class="recipes">

            <div class="grid-100 row controls">
                <div class="grid-30">
                    <select>
                        <option value="">All Categories</option>
                        <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
                        <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
                        <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
                        <option value="dessert">Dessert</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-40">
                    <input placeholder="Search"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-30">
                    <div class="flush-right">
                        <a th:href="@{/recipes/add-new-recipe}"><button>+ Add Recipe</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="grid-100 row addHover" th:each="recipe : ${recipes}">
                <a th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/detail|}">
                    <div class="grid-70">
                        <p>
                            <span><img th:src="@{/images/favorite.svg}" height="12px"/> </span>
                            <span th:text="${recipe.name}"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="hoverBlock">
                    <div class="grid-30">
                        <div class="flush-right">
                            <p>
                                <a th:href="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/edit|}"> <img th:src="@{/images/edit.svg}" height="12px"/> Edit </a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('recipeDeleteForm').submit();"> <img th:src="@{/images/delete.svg}" height="12px"/> Delete </a>
                                <form th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}" method="post" id="recipeDeleteForm">
                                </form>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @{|/recipes/ is a collection/array/list so you need to iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an `<a>` tag to submit the delete form:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('recipeDeleteForm').submit();"> <img th:src="@{/images/delete.svg}" height="12px"/> Delete </a>
                                <form th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}" method="post" id="recipeDeleteForm">
                                </form>
```

The solution is to use a button instead, inside the form tags, and eliminate the anchor:

```
<form th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/delete|}" method="post" id="recipeDeleteForm">
                                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                                </form>
```